# date_trunc in Athena error: Unknown type: interval

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena to pull in only month end eventdates where the max eventdate is '2023-05-31'

I tried the query below and received this error - **SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:20: Unexpected parameters (varchar(5), varchar) for function date_trunc. Expected: date_trunc(varchar(x), date) , date_trunc(varchar(x), time) , date_trunc(varchar(x), time with time zone) , date_trunc(varchar(x), timestamp) , date_trunc(varchar(x), timestamp with time zone)**

```
select distinct "eventdate"
from events_production.loan_3
where "eventdate" <= '20230531'
and  "eventdate" = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', "eventdate") + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'
```

So, I tried this instead but now receive this error - **SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:121: Unknown type: interval**

```
select distinct "eventdate"
from events_production.loan_3
where "eventdate" <= '20230531'
and  "eventdate" = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', date(date_format(cast(date_parse("eventdate", '%Y%m%d') as date),'%Y-%m-%d'))) + interval '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'
```

any reason Athena isn't recognizing the 'interval'

Comment: I don’t believe you can have multiple values in a single interval. Try DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', "eventdate") + INTERVAL '1 MONTH’  - INTERVAL ‘1 DAY'